# Group Header does not start on a new page even when 'Start on a new page' is checked

Tags: jasper-reports, report, expression, ireport

I need a specific text to come on a new page.
So I create a dummy group and add the field to the group.
But when I set property ' start on a new page' to true, it still continues with the Detail section.

Please help.

I am using IReport 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I believe the flag you are playing with forces the group header to appear at the top of a page, not at the top of all pages.  That is if you have 19.5 pages of detail, you will have the header on the top of page 1 and the top of page 20.  I believe you are seeing more than one page of detail, so it is not ready to redraw the group you defined.